Setting up GDAL in Docker
I’m trying to setup GDAL in Docker to support a Python back-end web server using Flask. After running docker compose up -d I’m receiving the following error:
Could not find gdal-config. Make sure you have installed the GDAL native library and development headers.

I tried a solution from a similar question on setting up Docker and GDAL for Django: How to add GDAL in docker to run with an alpine Docker image but this did not resolve the error:
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates tzdata
RUN apk add --no-cache –repository 
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing gdal

My Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10-alpine

COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY app /app/

ENV FLASK_APP=/app
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV FLASK_DEBUG=0

CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:1111", "app:app"]

My docker-compose:
services:
   backend:
      build:
         context: ./backend
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
          - '1111:1111'


In many cases a Debian-based Python image will be faster to build and maybe even smaller than an Alpine-based image because it can use prebuilt "wheel" format packages.  At that point, any of the apt-get answers from the question you link to should work.  Both questions just seem to be "how do I get GDAL installed"; how is this question different?

You can install the gdal and gdal-dev packages via apk and define the necessary paths so that the python libraries can find them.
FROM python:3.12-alpine

RUN apk upgrade --update
RUN apk add --no-cache build-base gcc gdal gdal-dev zlib

RUN export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
RUN export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
RUN export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
RUN export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# ...

Since the alpine package sources provide version 3.9.1 of gdal, it is necessary to use a compatible version under python. So this line is required within the requirements.
gdal==3.9.1
# ...


After clarifying the requirement more, it turns out that installing GDAL through the Dockerfile was not necessary in my case as I just needed to install it on my local Ubuntu environment first before I ran the Docker Compose to start up the back-end web server.
